# Why JMeter Ultimate Thread Groups create incorrect number of users?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

When I'm using the original JMeter Thread Groups and set 10 threads (users), it fires 10 external HTTP calls.

When I changed it to Ultimate Thread Groups (UTG) and set the following attributes...

- Start Threads Count = 10
- Initial Delay = 0
- Startup Time = 60
- Hold Load For = 30
- Shutdown Time = 10

...it fires thousands of external HTTP calls. Even the Stepping Thread Groups (STG) and Concurrency Thread Groups (CTG) also behave the same as UTG.

Why this happens when using non-original JMeter thread groups? I'm looking for ways to create 10 users that create 1 external HTTP call each (means 10 in total for the whole test plan) using UTG, STG or CTG but I don't really understand why this happens.

**Screenshots when using original Thread Group**

[image]

[image]

**Screenshots when using original Ultimate Thread Group**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario results in:

1. On 5th second of the test 1st virtual users starts
2. Within next 55 seconds remaining 9 virtual users start
3. 10 users are active for 30 seconds
4. Then each 1 second each 1 virtual user is being shut down

You're seeing much more than 10 requests because **once virtual user is kicked off it starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as it can** and the actual number of executed Samplers will mostly depend on your application response time. Check out [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/) for more comprehensive explanation.

---

If your goal is to execute 10 requests in 1 minute 40 seconds you need to use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) in order to limit JMeter to send 1 request per each 10 seconds.